# Trying to create an efficient way to produce a cross join with combined results

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm, cross-join

Let's assume we have these models:

```
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      classroom = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom......

class Course(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Grades(models.Model):
      student = models.ForeignKey(Student....
      course = models.ForeignKey(Course....
      grade = models.CharField(.....
```

I want to create the crossjoin of the courses and students, but with the grades in the table.

```
|          | Student A | Student B |
| Course 1 | 8         |           |
| Course 2 | 6         | 4         |
```

Please note that student B did not receive a grade for course 1 yet!

I currently solve this like this

```
query = list(product(courses, students)
grades = Grades.objects.all.....
for i, query_tuple in enumerate(query):
     grade = grades.filter(query_tuple[0], query_tuple[1]
     if grade: # Note 1
         # Here I add it to a list of the grades
```

But at the point of '# Note 1' it runs an query each time, which drastically decreases performance (A class can have up to 30 students with each more that 50 courses).

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe more in Django-ORM style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. Please do not make a query per table cell. This usually not a good idea.

We can first query for the `Course`s and `Student`s, and then make a 2d list, like:

```
courses = Course.objects.all()
students = Student.objects.filter(classroom=classroom)

coursemap = { c.pk: i for i, c in enumerate(courses) }
studentmap = { s.pk: i for i, s in enumerate(students)}

table = [[None] * len(student) for __ in range(len(courses))]

for grade in Grade.objects.filter(student__classroom=classroom):
    row = coursemap.get(grade.course_id)
    col = coursemap.get(grade.student_id)
    if row is not None and col is not None:
        table[row][col] = grade.grade
```

So at the end `table` is a list of lists of grades, with `None` if no grade exists. The *i,j*-th cell in the table refers to the grade of the *i*-th course in `courses` and the *j*-th student in `students`.

We can then pass the data like:

```
return render(
    request,
    'some_template.html',
    {'cols': students, 'rows': zip(students, table)}
)
```

and then render this like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&times;</th>
            {% for student in cols %}
                <th>{{ student.name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for course, grades in rows %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{ course.name }}</th>
                {% for grade in grades %}
                    <td>{{ grade|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can however use [**`django-pivot`** [PiPy]](https://pypi.org/project/django-pivot/) to do the job and remove the boilerplate code.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work over the past 30 min, but I can't seem to figure it out. I get a populated table, which is great, like I have to thank you a lot for that already! But when trying to get to display the table in the template in run into a problem, how would I print the course/student name when only the ids are inside the table? You can't normally return the object from the pk, right? Is writing a function to get that object what you recommend?

Comment: @MrDikke: that should be something like the template in the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah don't think I would've taught of that! Thank you so much!